# Step graph using a function block and scope in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, s-function

I'm trying to to get a step graph from the following code (extracted from my main project):

[image: Simulink model]

Code:

```
function y = fcn(~)
    tic;
    y = 0
    pause(5);
    y = 1;
    pause(3);
    y = 0;
    pause(5);
    timeVal = toc;
    fprintf("Simulation time: %f",timeVal);
end
```

But I'm getting a flat line graph in the scope.

[image: graph in scope]

I'm always getting the flat line corresponding to the last assigned value.
How do I get a plot for all the changes in the value of variable during execution?

Comment: I think you should really read the documentation of both `pause` https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pause.html and `Matlab function block` https://ch.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/what-is-a-matlab-function-block.html because neither of them do what you are trying to use them for. Is there a reason not to use  `Step block`? https://ch.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/step.html

Answer (score -1):

**1.-**

The function that you have defined is not the way to define a MATLAB function inside the **SIMULINK** block MatlabFunction, at least not to measure the **STEP RESPONSE of a SYSTEM** on the **SCOPE**.

[SIMULINK block MatlabFunction Help](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/what-is-a-matlab-function-block.html?searchHighlight=Simulink%20block%20matlab%20function&s_tid=srchtitle_support_results_1_Simulink%20block%20matlab%20function)

[SIMULINK Matlab function block properties](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/matlab-function-block-properties.html)

There's even an editor to generate **SIMULINK** Matlab block functions

[MATLAB BLOCK EDITOR help page](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/matlabfunctionblockeditor.html)

While we can write **MATLAB** functions similar to what you have posted in your question, to

1.1.- **Generate Step**

1.2.- **Feed Step** to System

1.3.- **Measure response**

**2.- Define a SAMPLE TIME**

As it is, **the scope does not have any time reference**, because the function you have written does not have a time reference.

The easiest way to supply a time reference to the scope is to

**PLUG AN INPUT SIGNAL TO THE FUNCTION BLOCK**

An input signal that goes through the Matlab function block, **generating and output that propagates the time reference supplied by the input signal.**

For instance, consider using the **step generator block** suggested in the following video.

**3.- WATCH THIS VIDEO** explaining how to build a basic step response in **SIMULINK**.

https://youtu.be/_uPZx9iDfbc?feature=shared

**4.- BUILD ONE LIKE THIS**

[image]

**5.- The Scope is flat because there is no input**

Once you feed a step into the system, then the scope is going to have a signal to display.

**6.- LEVEL-2 S-FUNCTION**

[Defining a level-2 S-function as explained here
https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/writing-level-2-matlab-s-functions.html](https://Defining%20a%20level-2%20S-function%20as%20explained%20here%20https://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/writing-level-2-matlab-s-functions.html)

**S-functions** can be even written in C or C++ .

Once having followed these steps, if still in any doubt how to proceed, please do not hesitate mentioning it with and additional comment, to see what can be done.

Thanks for time and attention.